# Vanilla PHP api allow only POST request

Tags: php, api, request

I added the following to header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

But I can still send any type of request, how I can make sure only POST is accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the method in your api by:

```
$requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 
if ($requestMethod !== 'POST') {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Only POST method is allowed";
}
```